# Direct3D9: after enabling mipmaps my texture coordinates seem to be wrong

Tags: c++, windows, directx, direct3d, mipmaps

I have a texture that contains symbols and characters that I use to put strings and icons on my final render target. To produce a string for example, I render every character as a single quad with the appropriate texture coordinates.

My problem starts when I try to use mipmaps for the texture containing all my symbols. Without mipmaps, everything works as intended. After changing only the `CreateTexture()` call to generate all mip levels and adding `D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENMIPMAP` to the usage parameter, I only get garbled output like this:

[image]

The texture is created like this:

```
CreateTexture(width, height, 0, D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC | D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENMIPMAP, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_texture, nullptr);
```

I use the following texture filtering when rendering:

```
SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR);
```

Everything that is rendered is still part of the texture but the texture coordinates seem to be all wrong somehow. I tried debugging this issue with PIX but there my render target looks exactly as intended. (I believe, PIX uses software rendering while my GPU is an Nvidia Quadro with the latest drivers.)

I don't really know where I should keep looking. My texture coordinates should be correct as everything works without mipmaps. Did I miss something when switching on mipmapping for this texture? Any ideas what could be causing this?

EDIT: I tried this with the reference driver (`D3DDEVTYPE_REF` instead of `D3DDEVTYPE_HAL`) and have the same problem, which suggests that it's not a driver issue but in the application code. Still, I have no idea where to look as it's working if I don't use mipmaps.

Comment: Are you sure your hardware supports auto-generation of mipmaps? Check `D3DCAPS2_CANAUTOGENMIPMAP` and/or call `CheckDeviceFormat` with `D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENMIPMAP` to be sure.

Comment: Yes, it does. Are there even any modern GPUs that don't support auto-generation of mipmaps?

Comment: Are there even any modern GPUs that don't support DirectX 11? ;-)

Comment: Due to XP support we started with DX9 and there was no time yet to switch to DX11.

Comment: I feel your pain - we've migrated some - but not all - DX9 to DX11 and it's much nicer to forget about DX9. However, if your problem doesn't show with software renderer, then that's why I suspected hardware and/or drivers. What's the exact return code from `CreateTexture`? It's not `D3DOK_NOAUTOGEN` is it?

Comment: It returns ``S_OK``. There are no errors, it just displays garbage. And mipmaps are such a fundamental feature that I wonder how there can be a hardware or driver error.

Comment: And yet it works ok with a software renderer, so that implies there are no problems with your code either. All of these can't be true (unless you're imagining the problem). I agree mipmaps are fundamental and in normal cases, they "just work".

Comment: Specifying `0` for the third parameter of `CreateTexture` should be enough to generate mipmaps automatically. Try not using `D3DUSAGE_AUTOGENMIPMAP` flag. If it doesn't help try calling `GenerateMipSubLevels` on the texture.

Comment: @fschoenm yes basically all of them. if the hardware did it, it would be one API call. however: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/GenerateMipMaps